# Scrapy: Looping through search results only returns first item

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping a site by going through the search page, then looping through all results within. However it only seems to be returning the first result for each page. I also don't think it's hitting the start page's results either.

Secondly, the price is returning as some sort of Unicode (£ symbol) - how can I remove it altogether just leaving the price?

```
 'regular_price': [u'\xa38.59'],
```

Here is the HTML:
http://pastebin.com/F8Lud0hu

Here's the spider:

```
import scrapy
import random
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from cdl.items import candleItem

class cdlSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = "cdl"
        allowed_domains = ["www.xxxx.co.uk"]
        start_urls = ['https://www.xxxx.co.uk/advanced_search_result.php']

        rules = [
                Rule(LinkExtractor(
                        allow=['advanced_search_result\.php\?sort=2a&page=\d*']),
                        callback='parse_listings',
                        follow=True)
        ]

        def parse_listings(self, response):
                sel = Selector(response)
                urls = sel.css('a.product_img')

                for url in urls:
                        url = url.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
                        return scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_item)

        def parse_item(self, response):

                candle = candleItem()

                n = response.css('.prod_info_name h1')

                candle['name'] = n.xpath('.//text()').extract()[0]


                if response.css('.regular_price'):
                        candle['regular_price'] = response.css('.regular_price').xpath('.//text()').extract()
                else:
                        candle['was_price'] = response.css('.was_price strong').xpath('.//text()').extract()
                        candle['now_price'] = response.css('.now_price strong').xpath('.//text()').extract()

                candle['referrer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer', None)
                candle['url'] = response.request.url

                yield candle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's returning only the first result because of your `parse_listing` method (you're returning the first url and you should be yielding it). I would do something like:

```
def parse_listings(self, response):
    for url in response.css('a.product_img::attr(href)').extract():
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)
```

In that case I would even do something like:

```
class CdlspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'cdlSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.xxxx.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.xxxx.co.uk/advanced_search_result.php']

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='advanced_search_result\.php\?sort=2a&page=\d*')),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='a.product_img'), callback='parse_item')
        ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        ...
        if response.css('.regular_price'):
            candle['regular_price'] = response.css('.regular_price::text').re_first(r'\d+\.?\d*')
        else:
            candle['was_price'] = response.css('.was_price strong::text').re_first(r'\d+\.?\d*')
            candle['now_price'] = response.css('.now_price strong::text').re_first(r'\d+\.?\d*')
        ...
        return candle
```

Comment: Thank you, the change from
    return scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_item)
To:
    yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_item)

Works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, follow up question sorry. Some of the prices I am scraping are into the thousands and are formatted with a comma, e.g £1,190.00. With these ones, the regex condition will match the price here just as "1". Normal prices work fine. Would you have a suggestion on how to amend this? Thanks

Comment: Change the regex `'\d+\.?\d*'` to `'(?:\d{1,3}[,\.])*\d\d'` , that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the £, just replace it with an empty string like this:

```
pricewithpound = u'\xa38.59'
price = pricewithpound.replace(u'\xa3', '')
```

To investigate the scrapy issue, can you please provide the HTML source ?